# Knapsack implementation not filling correctly. Have tried debugging for days now. Still learning

Tags: c++, dynamic, knapsack-problem

[Visualiazation of code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDqt2.png)
When I load this into a visualizer my table isn't being filled correctly with the minimum value of this knapsack problem variation what exactly is wrong? I realize this may seem like a lazy question but I've spent days on it and don't know what is wrong. I'm still learning.

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
void Minwater(int w[],int p[],int T,int n)/// Assumes n is last element of w[]
{
    int R[4][7];//Initialize array of n+1 row and T+1 cols
    for(int i = 0; i <= n+1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= T+1; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                R[i][j] = 0;
            else if (w[i - 1] <= j)
                R[i][j] = min(p[i - 1] + R[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]],R[i - 1][j]);
            else
                R[i][i] = R[i - 1][j];
       
        }
      cout<< R[n][T];
    }
  
}

int main() {
  int w[3]={1,2,3};
  int T=6;
  int p[3]={10,15,40};
  Minwater(w,p,T,4);
  return 0;
}
```

The table is suppose to take the minimum of two values
min(p[i - 1] + R[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]],R[i - 1][j])
but I seem to be filling it with all zeroes, and all the whole table doesn't end up filling.

Comment: `int R[4][7];//Initialize array of n+1 row and T+1 cols` -- This line doesn't initialize anything.  All it does is declare a two-dimensional array with who-knows-what values in it.  If you truly wanted to initialize it to `0`: `int R[4][7] = {};`

Comment: *I've spent days on it and don't know what is wrong.* -- If you used `std::array` instead of regular arrays, you would have been able to discover the problem in minutes, maybe seconds, and not days.  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbd4837aba88c098).  You have an out-of-bounds access.  Now you know what causes the problem, the fix to it -- it's all yours from here.

Comment: The subscripts were reversed, but even with that [the same error occurs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c16e0ee83e8ed6e).

Answer (score 0):

First I think we shouldn't access `i - 1` when `i == 0` that would cause unwanted behavior so best would be to set `R[i][j] = 0 when i == 0`

I also changed to max because if you wanna use min you should set all values to some infinity otherwise 0 will be the default in the whole grid

Also make sure your grid R is uninitialized to some value so that the max operation can be conclusive (I added  `= {0}` just to show we want all to be equal to zero you might want a for loop to initialize all of it)

```cpp
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
void Minwater(int w[],int p[],int T,int n)/// Assumes n is last element of w[]
{
    int R[4][7] = {0};//Initialize array of n+1 row and T+1 cols
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= T; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                R[i][j] = 0;
            else if (w[i - 1] <= j)
                R[i][j] = max(p[i - 1] + R[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]],R[i - 1][j]);
            else
                R[i][i] = R[i - 1][j];
       
        }
      cout<< R[n][T];
    }
  
}

int main() {
  int w[3]={1,2,3};
  int T=6;
  int p[3]={10,15,40};
  Minwater(w,p,T,4);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *you might want a for loop to initialize all of it* -- Technically speaking, using a `for` loop is not initialization -- it is *assignment*.  Assigning is different than initialization.

Comment: Changing to `std::array<std::array<int, 7>, 4> R = {}` and using `at()` shows that there is an out-of-bounds access here: `R[i][j] = 0;`

Comment: are we really nitpicking here hhh You are right though I only wanted to point out that the array might have values that are unknown that would cause the min/max function to behave differently than how we want them to.

Comment: I'm pointing out that the code has undefined behavior.  Note that this is posted as an answer on StackOverflow -- if you have knowledge or someone lets you know that the code has undefined behavior, the least thing you should do is mention it in the answer and/or diagnose the problem and edit the answer with the correction.  Here is the code [for reference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a727882ec86d581).  There is nothing wrong with knowing the answer will not work, but mention that it won't work.  Otherwise we get newbies copying and pasting the answer, and then are disappointed.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. In all fairness I wanted to show a general approach to make it work but you are right I made some changes to it. thank you for pointing it out